# Git: Removing submodule error

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm trying to remove submodule from my repo. This are the steps I'm using to remove the repo:

```
Delete the relevant section from the .gitmodules file.
Stage the .gitmodules changes git add .gitmodules
Delete the relevant section from .git/config.
Run git rm --cached path_to_submodule
```

But when I ran this command  `git rm --cached path_to_submodule` I get this error:

```
fatal: Please stage your changes to .gitmodules or stash them to proceed
```

If ran `git status` I get this message:

```
fatal: Not a git repository:path to submodule
```

Any of you knows why or how can I remove the submodule?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to first unregister the submodule.

```
git submodule deinit <path_to_submodule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing a submodule (deinit) might not be enough.

Before Git 2.25.2 (March 2020), Running "`git rm`" (or deinit) on a submodule failed unnecessarily when `.gitmodules` is only cache-dirty, which has been corrected.

See [commit 7edee32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7edee32985b1363e35e91c7358a9e60f2359fbba) (27 Jan 2020) by [David Turner (`csusbdt`)](https://github.com/csusbdt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a74c387](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a74c387495d1640537c5e163b053932ab1992156), 12 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git rm submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7edee32985b1363e35e91c7358a9e60f2359fbba): succeed if `.gitmodules` index stat info is zero
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: David Turner</sup>
>   <sup>Reported-by: Thomas Bétous</sup>
>
> The bug was that `ie_match_stat()` was used to compare if the stat info for the file was compatible with the stat info in the index, rather using `ie_modified()` to check if the file was in fact different from the version in the index.
>
> A version of this (with `deinit` instead of `rm`) was [reported here](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAPOqYV+C-P9M2zcUBBkD2LALPm4K3sxSut+BjAkZ9T1AKLEr+A@mail.gmail.com/).
>
> ```
> $ git submodule deinit Submodule1
> fatal: Please stage your changes to .gitmodules or stash them to proceed
> Submodule work tree 'Submodule1' contains local modifications; use
> '-f' to discard them
> ```
>
> It seems that in that case, the user's clone command left the index with empty stat info.
>
> The mailing list was unable to reproduce this.
>   But we (Two Sigma) hit the bug while using some plumbing commands, so I'm fixing it.
>
> I manually confirmed that the fix also repairs `deinit` in this scenario.