# Removing a submodule manually

Tags: git, git-rm, git-index

I tried removing manually the following submodule from my local repository:

components/**CtrlFuelSuppHtr**

Removed it from these three places: .git folder, components folder, and deleted it on .gitmodules.

But I get the following error when running any command like the one below. It seems that it still exists in the git index.

```
git submodule > status.txt
fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'components/CtrlFuelSuppHtr'
```

So removing it from cache:

```
git rm --cached components/CtrlFuelSuppHtr
**fatal: please stage your changes to .gitmodules or stash them to proceed**
```

So the problem is that it still exists in my cache, but I have manually deleted it from anywhere else and it's asking to stage or stash the changes.
I would like to completely deleted without having to commit or stash it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789152/git-removing-submodule-error

Comment: I tried deinitializing and then removing it from cache, but unfortunately it didn't help, it still asks for the changes to be committed or stashed

Comment: I found a solution, it was right in front of me. I just needed to stage the changes in .gitsubmodules, no need to commit, after that was able to run `git rm --cached components/CtrlFuelSuppHtr` and it worked